# ffmpeg: wmv files generated on Mac can't be played in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, ffmpeg, file-conversion, wmv

On Mac OS X 10.6.8, I converted a animated gif to a video file in wmv (a requested file format) by using

```
ffmpeg -i File.gif -s 400x400 NewFile.wmv
```

The video file played fine using VLC on Mac. 
The file can't be played on a Windows 7 machine using the Windows Media Player.  Is there a way that I can save the animated gif as a WMV file that can be played using the Windows Media Player on a Windows 7 machine?

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a codec for encoding instead. Try this.

```
ffmpeg -i input_gif -b:v 2M -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 output_wmv
```

You may find [this](https://walterebert.com/blog/creating-wmv-videos-with-ffmpeg/) important.